# Determining the type of node displayed using the \addplot command

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a plot of a rational function. I use `\addplots` to plot one point on it.  `TikZ` marks the point with a diamond.  I want to mark it with a dot. How do I specify the options to make the dot the same color as `blue` or a different color?  How do I specify the size?  Is the default size for a dot 1.5pt?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-42.5,xmax=42.5,
    samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-42.5,ymax=42.5,
    restrict y to domain=-42.5:42.5,
    xtick={},ytick={},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-40:64/41,blue] {(x + 16)/(x - 2)};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=32/13:40,blue] {(x + 16)/(x - 2)} node[above,pos=0.9,font=\footnotesize]{$y=\frac{x+16}{x-2}$};

\addplot[dashed, latex-latex, samples=2, domain=-42.5:42.5] {1} node[above,pos=0.1,font=\footnotesize]{$y=1$};
\addplot [dashed, latex-latex, samples=2, domain=-42.5:42.5] (2,x) node [pos=0.1, anchor=north, font=\footnotesize, sloped] {$x=2$};

\addplot coordinates{(5,7)} node[anchor=west,font=\footnotesize]{$(5,7)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `[mark=*,blue,mark size=2pt]` to the plot coordinate, where `mark=*` makes a little ball, `blue` is the colour and `mark size=2pt` is the size.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-42.5,xmax=42.5,
    samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-42.5,ymax=42.5,
    restrict y to domain=-42.5:42.5,
    xtick={},ytick={},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-40:64/41,blue] {(x + 16)/(x - 2)};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=32/13:40,blue] {(x + 16)/(x - 2)} node[above,pos=0.9,font=\footnotesize]{$y=\frac{x+16}{x-2}$};

\addplot[dashed, latex-latex, samples=2, domain=-42.5:42.5] {1} node[above,pos=0.1,font=\footnotesize]{$y=1$};
\addplot [dashed, latex-latex, samples=2, domain=-42.5:42.5] (2,x) node [pos=0.1, anchor=north, font=\footnotesize, sloped] {$x=2$};

\addplot[mark=*,blue,mark size=2pt] coordinates{(5,7)} node[anchor=west,font=\footnotesize]{$(5,7)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  You tell me that `mark=*` instructs `pgfplots` to mark that point (5,7) with a dot.  This seems like an odd "synonym."  What is the option if I wanted to mark this point with a square or a triangle or a diamond?

Comment: @user74973 See the [pgfplots manual](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf), *4.6.1 Markers*, page 79.